# How can I add get the value of a cell containing an emoji in Google Appscript?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

In appscript, when I check my logs, it tells me that in this case P2 is: Jan 1, 2023, 2:11:20 PM
Info

This part of the appscript is meant to add a note on the cell with any occurance of the emoji with the text "Move"

```
function onEdit(e) {
  
   var notes = {
    '': 'Move',
    'option 2': 'Easy Slow-Cooker Chipotle Chicken Chili',
    'option 3': 'Easy 30-Minute Swiss Pan Burgers With Rosemary-Mushroom Sauce',
    'option 4': 'Black Bean Edamame Burger',
    'option 5': 'Sriracha-Cashew Chicken Fried Rice',
    'option 6': 'Shrimp Fried Quinoa',
    'option 7': 'Chocolate Chip Brownie Cookies',
    'option 8': 'Dark Chocolate Chip And Sea Salt Cookies',
    'option 9': 'Easy 30-Minute Homemade Chicken Noodle Soup'

  }
  if (notes[e.value]) {
    return e.range.setNote(notes[e.value]);
  } 
}
```

it is working for the texts (option 2) for example. But not for the emojis. I've also tried picking up the emojis using stringFromCodePoint and by using the =CHAR reference to no avail.

[by the way, the code I'm using I found online- thank you to whoever shared it!]

Do you know of any ways for me to get the value of a cell with an emoji please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you show appears to work fine when you manually enter  in a cell — it will set the cell note to `Move`. It does not support copy and paste of cells, and does not attempt to find keys *among* other text, so it will do nothing when you paste `text that contains`  in a cell. This has nothing to do with whether the keys contain emojis.

To make the function insert a note when the text entered or pasted in the cell *contains* one of the keys, use `Range.getDisplayValue()` and `String.includes()`, like this:

```js
/**
* Simple trigger that runs each time the user hand edits the spreadsheet.
*
* @param {Object} e The onEdit() event object.
*/
function onEdit(e) {
  const notes = {
    '': 'Move',
    'option 2': 'Easy Slow-Cooker Chipotle Chicken Chili',
    'option 3': 'Easy 30-Minute Swiss Pan Burgers With Rosemary-Mushroom Sauce',
    'option 4': 'Black Bean Edamame Burger',
    'option 5': 'Sriracha-Cashew Chicken Fried Rice',
    'option 6': 'Shrimp Fried Quinoa',
    'option 7': 'Chocolate Chip Brownie Cookies',
    'option 8': 'Dark Chocolate Chip And Sea Salt Cookies',
    'option 9': 'Easy 30-Minute Homemade Chicken Noodle Soup',
  };
  const value = e.value || e.range.getDisplayValue();
  Object.keys(notes).some(key => {
    if (value.includes(key)) {
      e.range.setNote(notes[key]);
      return true;
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time! I've tried my code out in a fresh spreadsheet, and yours also, and they don't seem to be working for me. Did you do anything different to me? https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BvAl5RCWj8DVv8rttWZShlXNJ1T01w2uuq7Gm3wSSgc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: The code I gave you appears to work fine in your sample spreadsheet when you _enter text manually_ in a cell. The issue is probably that you are using copy and paste to make new shoes. Edited the answer to support copy and paste as well.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help with this! I'm going to look up the parts of the code to understand what's happening here as this is so useful!